# Run app edit configuration error

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

Please help, I am trying to run my app built in android studio. When I hit run I get the Edit Configuration screen with the following error.

> Error: The apk for your currently selected variant is not signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant.

I have tried Generating Signed SDK, I have tried Cleaning and Rebuilding the project and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change build variant mode

follow steps

1.Click Build variant on the left side of the IDE window.

2.Module app >> chnage build variant **release to debug**

please check screenshot

[image]

Hope this will help you